# Finding a match against a comma separated attribute with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a simple way to achieve this or do I need to think of some looping approach:

I have some HTML like:

`<div tags="class, school, work">...</div>`

And I want to obtain all divs with one (or more) of those tags. I know I can a full match i.e. 
`document.querySelectorAll('[tags="class, school, work"]');`

However can I search for just the one?

`document.querySelectorAll('[tags="school"]');`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is using this selector `[tags*="school"]`

*The `[attribute*=value]` selector matches every element whose attribute value containing a specified value*

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[tags*="school"]').textContent);
```

```html
<div tags="class, school, work">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - however - does that work with a comma list does it i.e. `document.querySelector('[tags*="school, school"]')`
Tried but couldn't get it

Comment: was checking - but re-read your answer `containing a specified value` so I guess not

Comment: `document.querySelector('[tags*="school"],[tags*="work"]')` seems to work - look valid to you?

Comment: Depending on what you mean, if you want to select the element if it has both school and some other value like class you could do `querySelector('[tags*="school"][tags*="class"]')` if you want more than one element with either school or class then you would have the comma inbetween the two like `querySelectorAll('[tags*="school"],[tags*="class"]')`

Comment: @userMod2 that comma works as an `OR` logical operator.